# xml etree not writing changes to file

Tags: python, xml, file-writing, xml.etree

I'm working on a program that will open an XML file, alter a few values, and save it as a new file. When I run it, it looks like everything is fine. I use print to look at what the system sees when I run the program, and the print command shows the correct value, but when I look at the actual file it generated, it hasn't written this value.

A lot of the code isn't actually about writing the file, and it's a little bit convoluted, but this is the part that actually does the file alterations.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import os
HOA = MeasureUtility.convertToInches(HOA)
    HOA = HOA+buryDepth
    oldHOA = MeasureUtility.convertToInches(oldHOA)
    fullOldHOA = int(oldHOA+buryDepth)
    poleChild = pole.find("PPLChildElements")
    insulators = poleChild.findall("Insulator")

    for i in insulators:
        insulatorAttr = i.find("ATTRIBUTES")
        insulatorValues = insulatorAttr.findall("VALUE")

        for iv in insulatorValues:
            if iv.attrib["NAME"] == "CoordinateZ":
                height = int(round(float(iv.text)))
                print("The calculated height: {0} || The researched height: {1}".format(fullOldHOA, height))

                if fullOldHOA == height:
                    iv.text = (str(HOA))
                    print("Insulator Height: {0}".format(etree.tostring(iv)))
                else:
                    continue
        
        

mytree.write(AftersFolder + "\\" + title)
```

I'm not sure if the xml file is relevant, but if it's deemed important, I'd be happy to post it, it's just long, and ultimately my issue is that where I adjust iv.text, and then write the file, the text in that tag remains exactly the same in the saved file as it was in the original.

Edit:
The full code for this aspect of the program is below.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import os
import MeasureUtility
#MeasureUtility is a module I made to affect normal measurements, such as converting a measurement to inches, to feet, or simply adjusting how a measurement value is perceived.
import numpy

def InstallOrChange(HOA, jobName, scid, oldHOA = 0):
    global PPLXFile
    if PPLXFile == "" or PPLXFile is None:
        return
    global root
    title = "{0}_{1}_AFTER.pplx".format(jobName, scid)
    buryDepth = 0

    mytree = etree.parse(PPLXFile)
    myroot = mytree.getroot()
    root = myroot
    scene = myroot.find("PPLScene")
    rootChild = scene.find("PPLChildElements")
    pole = rootChild.find("WoodPole")
    poleattr = pole.find("ATTRIBUTES")
    poleStats = poleattr.findall("VALUE")
    for x in poleStats:
        if x.attrib["NAME"] == "BuryDepthInInches":
            buryDepth = float(x.text)
    print(scid)
    if oldHOA == 0:
        #We are not looking for an old HOA, so don't worry!
        child = CreateNewElement("PPLChildElements", pole)
        Insulator = CreateNewElement("Insulator", child)
        Attr = CreateNewElement("ATTRIBUTES", Insulator)
        #Create new elements within XML document here
        #This part is working fine, I have no issues with this.
        
    else:
        HOA = MeasureUtility.convertToInches(HOA)
        HOA = HOA+buryDepth
        oldHOA = MeasureUtility.convertToInches(oldHOA)
        fullOldHOA = int(oldHOA+buryDepth)
        poleChild = pole.find("PPLChildElements")
        insulators = poleChild.findall("Insulator")

        for i in insulators:
            insulatorAttr = i.find("ATTRIBUTES")
            insulatorValues = insulatorAttr.findall("VALUE")

            for iv in insulatorValues:
                if iv.attrib["NAME"] == "CoordinateZ":
                    height = int(round(float(iv.text)))
                    print("The calculated height: {0} || The researched height: {1}".format(fullOldHOA, height))

                    if fullOldHOA == height:
                        iv.text = (str(HOA))
                        print("The old height: {0}, Insulator Height: {1}".format(height, etree.tostring(iv)))
                        #When this print command is run, it prints the appropriate response, and shows that the text has been altered.
                    else:
                        continue
            
            

    mytree.write(AftersFolder + "\\" + title)
```

And the code that calls that function:

```
for b in boltHoles:
        boltHoleMin = b-.34
        boltHoleMax = b+.34
        if HOA == b:
            HOA = b
        if HOA > boltHoleMax:
            HOA = HOA
        if HOA < boltHoleMax and HOA > b:
            HOA = b
        if HOA < b and HOA > boltHoleMin:
            HOA = boltHoleMin
        if index == 0:
            PPLXUtility.InstallOrChange(HOA, jobName, scid)
        else:
            PPLXUtility.InstallOrChange(HOA, jobName, scid, b)
```

Comment: A few items to note.  1) Please format your code such that it's indented properly. 2) what is ```mytree``` defined as?  3) ```AftersFolder + "\\" + title``` is prone to errors and isn't platform-agnostic.  Use either ```os.path.join``` or ```Pathlib```.  4) Does the path ```AftersFolder``` exist?

Comment: The code is actually indented as it is in the file. mytree is the parsed original file. The path is definitely not perfect, but it is operating, and AftersFolder does exist.

The files are generated, they are just exact duplicates of the original file.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve]. We cannot run the code in the question.

Comment: We still cannot run the code in the question. There are no `import` statements, for example. You have not made an attempt to trim the code down in order to provide complete but **minimal** code.

Comment: I am sorry to be such an insufferable nag, but you still haven't provided a [mcve]. Please trim the code down much more. For example, only include `import` statements that are actually needed. Please provide ONE code snippet that demonstrates the problem. Test the trimmed code before posting it. Also post an XML sample that can be used for debugging.

Comment: Not insufferable, at all. I need to learn, and the only way that's going to happen is to make me redo this process until I get to the point I vow to never make these mistakes again. I will get that prepped ASAP.